# regex match all error codes where error code does NOT equal '0'

Tags: regex

I thought this would be an easy one but I am doing something wrong.

I have tons of loggings where a certain line 'ErrorCode: [number]' can be found. I'd like to have a list of all occurrences where [number] does not equal '0'.

regex: `ErrorCode\:[^0]`

but this also matches with ErrorCode:[space]

how do I make the inverse match "mandatory" so that ErrorCode: 0 no longer matches?

Comment: BTW, are you using it in some external tool or in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex would allow all errors, including those for which the error code contains a zero (without being equal to zero):

```
ErrorCode\:(?:[1-9]|\d{2,})\b
```

Or, with a different approach:

```
ErrorCode\:(?!0)\b
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use a `[1-9]` character class:

```
ErrorCode:[1-9]
```

It will match `ErrorCode:` followed with any digit from `1` to `9` excluding `0`.

To *extract* the number, use

```
ErrorCode:([1-9][0-9]*)
```

and grab Group 1 value. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jMUQh7/1).

To match `ErrorCode:010` (with leading zeros) and not `ErrorCode:000`, use

```
ErrorCode:0*([1-9][0-9]*)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jMUQh7/2).

**Details**:

- `ErrorCode:` - a literal substring
- `0*` - zero or more `0` chars
- `([1-9][0-9]*)` - Group 1 matching a sequence of:

  - `[1-9]` - any ASCII digit but `0`
  - `[0-9]*` - any zero or more  ASCII digits.

Comment: careful though, error code `102` would not be caught by these expressions... see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44453700/734335

Comment: @MathieuRodic: OP is interested in the boolean return value as far as I understand. I infer it from the question.